# haskell write to file it if it does not exists before reading

Tags: file, haskell, io

I am learning haskell and am stumbled upon the `parse error on input contents'` compilation error.

*What i want to do :*

I store my previous session state state in a file. I read this file before starting the program. However, during the first run of program, file may not exist. In this case, i want to first create file first with default value and then proceed ahead.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    -- Take input
   let fileName = "ashish-temp.txt"

   let dummyBoard = take 5 $ repeat "-----"

   fileExist <- doesFileExist fileName

   if False == fileExist
   then writeFile fileName $ unlines dummyBoard

   -- getting an error on this line
   contents <- readFile fileName

   -- do processing () :)

   --  i want the value in contents
   putStrLn "Done"
```

Also, i think that rather than writing `dummyBoard` to the file i can just initialize the contents with `dummyBoard`. But i also failed in doing it. And i guess the way should be the same for both.

Please help. 
Thanks.

**Edit** Solution:

`else` is required for every `if` in haskell.

Also another problem that you would face after this problem is :
`*** Exception: ashish-temp.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)`

use `import qualified System.IO.Strict as S` and `S.redFile` for reading file.

Comment: Where's your `else`? You probably wanted to use `when` instead of `if`

Comment: i thought that `else` is not necessary. I also could not find any doc on `when` usage.

Comment: `else` is mandatory in Haskell (otherwise, what would `10 + (if 3==4 then 2)` be?). For `when` you need to `import Control.Monad`

Comment: Why are you writing `if False == ...`? This seems unnatural.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I have edited the question. Actually "I store my previous session state state in a file. I read this file before starting the program. However, during the first run of program, file may not exist. In this case, i want to first create file first with default value and then proceed ahead."

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz        Can i initialize `contents` with the `dummyBoard` in `then` case `else` initialize it after reading from the file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some problem with your codebase:

- You are missing the `else` part of your `if` expression. In Haskell, since `if` is an expression , it would need the `else` part as opposed to other languages where the `if-else` are statements and the else part is not mandatory.
- What exactly is `dim` ? You have to define it.

A working program which shows similar in concept of what you want to do will look like this:

```
main :: IO()
main = do

   let fileName = "somefile.txt"

   fileExist <- doesFileExist fileName

   if not fileExist
   then writeFile fileName "something"
   else return ()

   contents <- readFile fileName
   -- do stuff with contents here

   putStrLn "Done"
```

Comment: i would remove `dim` that was some refactoring isssue.

Comment: i want to do the `do stuff` part after writing to the file. i do not have any `else` logic. Can i iniitalize `contents` with `dummyBoard` in that case ? How ?

Comment: @AshishNegi In that case you can just give `return ()` in the else part. After that read the file and put your logic there.

Comment: I am sorry but i meant that i am using the file only for initializating the data. I have to `do the stuff` always. either with `data from file` or with `dummyBoard`.

Comment: @AshishNegi Put the logic part after the `if - else` expression.

Comment: 1. you have a return () in your else. 2. how to inilialize `contents` with `dummyBoard`

Comment: @AshishNegi I think you are confusing with the word `return ()`. Haskell `return` has a different meaning that other language's `return`. `return` is not the control - exit path of program. When you put the logic after `if-else`, it will be executed even if it goes to the `else` part of your `if` expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71785/discussion-between-ashish-negi-and-sibi).

Comment: `if condition then action else return ()` is usually better written `when condition action`, which in practice usually ends up being `when (condition) $ action`.

Answer (score 1):

You had a second part of the question which hasn't been answered yet.

> Also, i think that rather than writing `dummyBoard` to the file i can just initialize the contents with `dummyBoard`. But i also failed in doing it. And i guess the way should be the same for both.

Indeed you can, as follows:

```
contents <- if fileExist
    then readFile fileName
    else return $ unlines dummyBoard
```